# A compact Riemann surface with a finite set of points removed is parabolic

Tags: riemann-surfaces, geometric-analysis

A Riemann surface $\mathcal{R}$ is called parabolic if it is not compact and doesn't carry a negative non-constant subharmonic function, and is called hyperbolic if it carries a negative non-constant subharmonic function.

**Question**: Let $\mathcal{X}$ be a compact Riemann surface with a finite set of points removed. Then how to show that $\mathcal{X}$ is parabolic?  Can any one give me some references?

**Remark**: It might be more common to say that a Riemann surface is hyperbolic if it carries a complete hyperbolic metric. But I don't mean it here.  The terminology here is called function-theoretic classification.  The question above appears in many lectures, but none gives a proof. For example, see Page.22 of this lecture  https://indico.ictp.it/event/a14295/session/1/contribution/5/material/1/0.pdf

Comment: This is false, if you remove at least 3 points from the sphere, the resulting surface is hyperbolic. (Your terminology is also somewhat non-standard, compare here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_surface#Parabolic_Riemann_surfaces  )

Comment: @ChristianRemling  I know that classification, but don't mean it.  A thrice punctured sphere carries a hyperbolic  structure, but I don't know whether it carries a negative non-constant subharmonic function.

Comment: This is the classification used in, e.g. Ahlfors and Sario (_Riemann surfaces_, PUP 1968). Maybe you can find something in there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a simple removability theorem for subharmonic functions: if it is bounded from above in a neighborhood of an isolated singularity then this singularity is removable.

Proof. Suppose our singularity is at 0, and our function is $u$ defined subharmonic and bounded in
$|z|<R$. Let $$u_\epsilon=u+\epsilon\log|z|.$$
For any $r\in(0,R)$ let $v_r$ be the soluton of Dirichlet problem (Poisson integral) for
$|z|<r$ with boundery values $u+\epsilon\log r$.
Then by Maximum Principle, $u_r\leq v_r$ in $\delta<|z|<r$, where $\delta$ is sufficiently small. Letting $\epsilon\to 0$ we conclude that
$u\leq v_r$. Now define $$\tilde{u} (0)=\limsup_{z\to 0} u(z),$$ and $\tilde u(z)=u(z)$ for $z\neq 0$.
Then $\tilde{u}$ is subharmonic by the definition
of a subharmonic function.

Comment: Could you be more specific? I can only find theorems on removable singularities of harmonic functions, but not subharmonic.

Comment: @gaoqiang: Sorry, Carleson's book indeed does not contain this. I included a proof.